# Retrieving escape character (\) from variable

Tags: mysql, sql, powershell, escaping, string-literals

So I'm trying to write a query in SQL that retrieves everything after the backslash. What I'm doing right now to get the position of the backslash is this:

INSTR('xx\yy', '\\')

The problem is that the escape character is being executed before the search so it will never find the character. I know this is happening because LENGTH('xx\yy') returns 4.

Ideally I would put a second escape character in but I can't do that because I'm retrieving the value from whoami.exe and putting it into a variable. So my variable looks something like 'company\username'. Obviously I would like to retrieve username but the escape character is evaluated before I can get its position.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks

Comment: Are you formulating this sql statement in powershell?  Otherwise why is powershell tagged on this question?

Comment: I bet the problem goes away if you use a parameterized query

Comment: We need to see the entire query.

Comment: Since PowerShell is tagged, `(whoami) -replace '.*\\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one backslash

```
("Part1\Part2" -split "\\")[1]
```